# Error 400 in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am having issue deleting records. Each time i click on the delete button on the Manage page, it triggers "Error 400. Your request is invalid"

Below is the delete method

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
         if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest){

            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

            // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
                if(!isset($_GET['ajax'])){
                    $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
                }

         }
         else{
            throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
         }

    }
```

What could be wrong with that code?

Comment: Try turn off Csrf validation.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#$enableCsrfValidation-detail

Comment: Try *using* CSRF validation. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-best-practices.html#avoiding-csrf

Comment: Are you sure you're making a POST request instead of a GET request?

Answer (score 1):

Your delete method only responds to the POST request. Make sure your button is set to submit a POST request to the controller/action

Answer (score 1):

i was able to resolve the issue. The reason why you get "Error 400. Your request is invalid" on delete is when you attached more than one jquery plugin. By default, Yii registers jquery library.

Here is the file

```
**<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/asset/js/lib/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>**
```

Avoid adding another jquery lib.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Agreed, removing jQuery 3.3.1 resolved my issue, I was loading jQuery 3.3.1 and the default jQuery from yii installation.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to uncomment or remove in your controller a line generated by gii:

'PostOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete some records using Ajax delete then please follow.

This is my delete button and i set it to ajax link

echo CHtml::ajaxLink(' Delete', $this->createUrl('/controller/action/id/' . 123), array('success' => 'rowdelete(' . 123 . ')', 'type' => 'GET'), array('confirm' => "Are you sure you want to deleted."));

now in controller use default action

public function actionDelete($id) {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

```
    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if (!isset($_GET['ajax'])){
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('CityDel', 'City Deleted Successfully');
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
}
```